# Condição num select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Preciso criar um *SELECT* que contenham apenas registros de um valor x em diante. Por exemplo, retornar apenas os filmes com número de cópias maior que 5

**Meu Select**

```
router.get('/filmes', (req, res) =>{
    execSQLQuery('SELECT IF(copias > 5) from filmes', res);
});
```

**Tabela FIlmes**

```
CREATE TABLE filme(
id int not null Primary Key Auto_Increment,
titulo varchar(255) not null,
diretor varchar(255) not null,
copias int not null
);
```

**Erro retornado no Insomnia**

```
{
    "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
    "errno": 1064,
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') from filmes' at line 1",
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "SELECT IF(copias > 5) from filmes"
}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM filmes WHERE copias > 5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para utilizar condições no MySQL é necessário entender das cláusulas que ele possui, então neste caso você pode utilizar o **WHERE** (que significa "Onde", se traduzido), ou seja, você indicará para buscar os registros **ONDE** o número for maior que 5, como irei mostrar abaixo.

```
SELECT * FROM filmes WHERE copias > 5
```

Caso precisa selecionar entre um certo número e outro, por exemplo dos números 5 ao 50, você pode utilizar a cláusula **BETWEEN** (que significa "Entre", se traduzido), ou seja, você indicará para buscar os registros que estiverem **ENTRE** dois valores, sempre desta forma, como irei mostrar abaixo.

```
SELECT * FROM filmes WHERE copias BETWEEN 5 AND 50
```

Caso precise selecionar somente o número 5, pode utilizar a cláusula **IN**, (que significa "Dentro", se traduzido), ou seja, você indicará que necessita apenas dos registros que contenham o valor 5 **DENTRO** do campo cópias, desta como irei mostrar abaixo

```
SELECT * FROM filmes WHERE copias IN (5)
```

Comment: Olá,o in é igual ao where ?

Comment: o Where indica onde deverá ser buscado, e o IN indica que deve correr a tabela e capturar somente os registros com valor 5 no caso do exemplo acima. Onde Where indica que na tabela filmes eu quero buscar no campo copias os valores IN ou seja dentro deste campo que possuam valor 5

Comment: leia a resposta e entenderá, creio que deixei claro o suficiente, caso contrário estude as cláusulas do MySQL. Where significa ONDE e IN significa DENTRO,  entende ?

Comment: será nestes caso, mas o IN, voce pode selecionar mais de um número, na cláusula, por exemplo IN (5,10,15,20)

Comment: Agora entendi,Obrigado !

Comment: como eu disse, estude

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM FILME WHERE COPIAS > 5
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/120769/1

Answer (score 2):

A sua Query SQL está errada, o correto seria:

`SELECT * FROM filmes WHERE copias > 5`

segue uma referência de sintaxe: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp